# How to give java path in ubuntu

Tags: mysql, java-8, ubuntu-15.04

I am facing problem setting up java path while installing mysql database in my ubuntu PC. The procedure shows the following and i hav no idea for setting the java path

> Error: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java not found or not a valid JDK
>   Type the full pathname of a JDK installation (or Ctrl-C to quit), the path will be stored in /home/devkrishna/.sqldeveloper/4.1.0/product.conf
>   /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
>   Error: Java home /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java is not a JDK.
>   Running SQL Developer under a JRE is not supported.
>
> If this Java VM is actually a full JDK installation, add
>   'SetSkipJ2SDKCheck true' to one of the following files.
>   Otherwise specify a different Java JDK location with a
>   SetJavaHome directive in one of the following files:
>     /home/devkrishna/.sqldeveloper/4.1.0/product.conf
>     /opt/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper/bin/sqldeveloper.conf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Open terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>)
- Type

  ```
  sudo gedit .bashrc
  ```
- Enter password of ubuntu user
- Go to last line of the file
- Type below code in new line

  ```
  export JAVA_HOME=enter_java_path_here
  export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
  eg: export JAVA_HOME=/home/pranav/jdk1.8.0_131
      export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
  ```
- Save the file
- Type

  ```
  source ~/.bashrc
  ```

  in terminal
- Done

Answer (score 1):

The first error looks like you don't have openjdk-7 for some reason it looks like it is also looking for openjdk-8. Install at-least one of them with :

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

and/or

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

Comment: I already have java installed but the main problem is about setting up java path while installing mysql database

Comment: The path's seem to already be the correct locations if it is installed normally.  Are you trying to get it to use an alternative version?

Comment: I had used used java 1.7.0 previously but now i am using java1.8.0 and the problem was faced during my transistion from 1.7.0 to 1.8.0

Comment: Did you use apt-get to install from the Ubuntu repositories or did you download the JDK 1.8 from somewhere else?

Comment: From the error message I am guessing it is coming not mysql but  a custom install of sqldeveloper. Have you checked http://www.tomecode.com/2013/12/26/sql-developer-4-0-how-to-change-the-location-of-java-home/ ?

Comment: I need this for linux and not for ubuntu

Comment: The title of the question says Ubuntu. Perhaps you should ask a new question: "How do I specify the JDK path for SQL Developer in Linux?" with oracle-sqldeveloper and linux tags instead o  the mysql and ubuntu-15.04 tags.